# Implicitly Convert Generic and Non-Generic Subtypes in Scala

Tags: generics, scala, implicit-conversion

Assume you want to add some methods to all Iterables. That can look like this:

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

class Foo[P, S[X] <: Iterable[X]](val s : S[P]) {
  def bar(j : P)(implicit bf : CanBuildFrom[S[P],P,S[P]]) : S[P] = {
    val builder = bf(s)
    builder ++= s
    builder += j
    builder.result
  }

  def oneBar(j : P)(implicit bf : CanBuildFrom[S[P],P,S[P]]) : P = bar(j).head
}

implicit def iter2foo[P, S[X] <: Iterable[X]](s : S[P]) = new Foo[P,S](s)
```

Now, code like

```
println(Seq(1,2,3,4) bar 5)
```

compiles and executes smoothly. However,

```
println((1 to 4) bar 5)
```

causes

```
error: value bar is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive 
with scala.collection.immutable.Range.ByOne
```

I figured this might be since the implicit conversion demands (?) that the parameter's type has a type parameter (which `Range` has not). But

```
implicit def iter2foo[P, S <: Iterable[P]](s : S) = new Foo[P,Iterable](s)
```

does not change anything. Note that `Range` extends `Iterable[Int]`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I write one implicit conversion that applies to all subtypes of `Iterable`, wether generic or not?

**Edit:** I just notices that the much simpler

```
implicit def iter2foo[P](s : Iterable[P]) = new Foo[P,Iterable](s)
```

works as intended (on REPL). Or does it? Are there drawbacks of this solution?

**Edit 2:** The drawback is that the static result type of `bar` will only be `Iterable[P]`, not the more specific type. The constructed collection has the correct (actual) type, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, it doesn't matter that `Range` extends `Iterable[Int]`, this is indeed a problem with arity of type params.  It's a deep one too, even the core library suffers it in places (just look at the comments in `Manifest`)

You'll also encounter it if wanting to use Maps, Strings, etc. as though they were `Iterable`.

The only solution I've found is to define multiple implicit conversions to the pimp type.

**UPDATE**

The problem here is in inferring the type parameter `P` from the supplied argument, which doesn't appear to have a type parameter.  You're essentially trying to do for a type-constructor what extractors will do for a regular constructor, and polymorphism is getting in the way.

Your edited example works because this particular inference isn't needed, the catch is that you can now only return an `Iterable`, and so lose much of the benefit of `CanBuildFrom`

If that's not a problem, then it's a simpler solution, so roll with it.

Otherwise, you'll need different implicits for each possible arity of the types you want to pimp.

**UPDATE 2**

Consider how the compiler might handle your different expressions when trying to determine if a `Range` is a valid argument:

Take 1:

```
implicit def iter2foo[P, S[X] <: Iterable[X]](s : S[P]) = new Foo[P,S](s)
```

- `S` is a higher-kinded type, of kind `* => *`
- `Range` is a simple type, of kind `*`
- The kinds don't match so it's invalid

Take 2:

```
implicit def iter2foo[P, S <: Iterable[P]](s : S) = new Foo[P,Iterable](s)
```

- Same problem, `S` is still of kind `* => *` the argument doesn't match

Take 3:

```
implicit def iter2foo[P](s : Iterable[P]) = new Foo[P,Iterable](s)
```

- Having had the parameter supplied, `Iterable[P]` is a simple type of kind `*`
- `Range` passes this first hurdle
- The second check is that `Range` is a subclass of `Iterable[P]` for some `P`
- It is, with `P` inferred as `Int`
- The compiler is happy that all inference, bounds checking, etc. has succeeded

Comment: It should not work for `String` (since it is only viewable as `Seq`), but it should for `Map`, `Range` and other poor creatures. If it is a problem of arity, why does the second version not work? How can I define a second implicit conversion that catches all subtypes of `Iterable` without type parameter?

Comment: @update: I see. It is not clear to me why the inferrer does not consider supertypes, however. Since you can not extend the same trait with different parameters (?), this should yield an unambiguous result. As for my simpler version, it creates the correct (dynamic) type of collection but can only type it `Iterable` statically. That is you get the "under the hood" advantages of `CanBuildFrom`, but not the typing advantages.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to explain in a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, but I understood as much. My point is: In take 1 (or even 2), why does the compiler not walk up the supertype linearisation of `Range` after being unable to match, and repeat the steps you mention? Sure, it would increase compiler runtime even more, but is possible, right? It is peculiar that every instance of `Range` is an `Iterable[Int]` but is at this point not treated as such, as if the inferrer had forgotten the fact.

Comment: @Raphael - It's absolutely possible that it *could* be done that way, but it currently isn't and so the failure occurs when testing for Kind equality. Rest assured that this issue is known by the core Scala dev team, though I don't know when to expect a resolution, it's harder to fix than it looks!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Wanted to make sure I am not being dense or something, missing an obvious obstacle.

Comment: "Otherwise, you'll need different implicits for each possible arity of the types you want to pimp." -- can you please explain how to do that? I only came up with a solution that defines one conversion for each concrete parameterless subtype, which is obviously bad.